# Why sort shows different behavior while sorting a long array and short array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have and two `arrays` of `objects` which has two properties `same(0)for all` and `value(0,1,2,...)`. I created both arrays using for loop. I sorted the array on base of `same`. The `long` changes but `short` don't
I only want to know why this all happens
Why even changes the `long` array

```js
let short = [];
for(let i = 0;i < 5;i++){
  short.push({same:0,value:i});
}
let long = []
for(let i = 0;i < 16;i++){
  long.push({same:0,value:i});
}
//It returns same array with same order
console.log(short.sort((obj1,obj2) => obj1.same - obj2.same));
//It returns array with different order
console.log(long.sort((obj1,obj2) => obj1.same - obj2.same));
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce that issue. Tested with chrome console. If you still have an issue then post the output.

Comment: You're using sort wrong. `sort` takes 2 arguments.

Comment: the `.sort` function has two parameters - value `a` and value `b`, so you probably should be doing `.sort((obja, objb) => obja.same - objb.same)`

Comment: `sort` uses different algorithms depending on the size of the array. Given your broken comparison function, they behaved unexpected in different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort

This behavior depends on implementation. Your sorting algorithm saves the order if the sorting implementation is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) and has an unpredictable behavior otherwise. Some engines use different algorithms depending on array length. Sometimes instability may only be seen in arrays of some length.

For example, Node.js 10 with V8 6.8 wil output:

```
[ { same: 0, value: 0 },
  { same: 0, value: 1 },
  { same: 0, value: 2 },
  { same: 0, value: 3 },
  { same: 0, value: 4 } ]
[ { same: 0, value: 8 },
  { same: 0, value: 0 },
  { same: 0, value: 2 },
  { same: 0, value: 3 },
  { same: 0, value: 4 },
  { same: 0, value: 5 },
  { same: 0, value: 6 },
  { same: 0, value: 7 },
  { same: 0, value: 1 },
  { same: 0, value: 9 },
  { same: 0, value: 10 },
  { same: 0, value: 11 },
  { same: 0, value: 12 },
  { same: 0, value: 13 },
  { same: 0, value: 14 },
  { same: 0, value: 15 } ]
```

While Node.js 11 with V8 7.0 with stable sort wil output:

```
[ { same: 0, value: 0 },
  { same: 0, value: 1 },
  { same: 0, value: 2 },
  { same: 0, value: 3 },
  { same: 0, value: 4 } ]
[ { same: 0, value: 0 },
  { same: 0, value: 1 },
  { same: 0, value: 2 },
  { same: 0, value: 3 },
  { same: 0, value: 4 },
  { same: 0, value: 5 },
  { same: 0, value: 6 },
  { same: 0, value: 7 },
  { same: 0, value: 8 },
  { same: 0, value: 9 },
  { same: 0, value: 10 },
  { same: 0, value: 11 },
  { same: 0, value: 12 },
  { same: 0, value: 13 },
  { same: 0, value: 14 },
  { same: 0, value: 15 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/compareFunction/Global_Objects/Array/sort) compare function takes **2** parameters; the 1st parameter is an item and the 2nd is another item.

In your OP you're passing only 1 parameter;

Here's how it should look:

```js
let short = []
let long = []

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  short.push({same:0, value: i})
}

for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
  long.push({same:0, value: i})
}

console.log('short')
console.log(short.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value))

console.log('long')
console.log(long.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value))
```

Comment: Why the first obj of second  `console.log` is still not correct.First object has `value:8`

Comment: That's just another copypasta error from your own code. You should be checking the `value` prop, not the `same` prop. I've edited my post.